# How to apply a underline style to piece of text

Tags: html, css

Whenever hover, I want to apply a underline style to part of string.

ex)
[image]

Here is a my code.

HTML

```
<a class="test">
  <i>1</i><span>23</span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.test:hover span{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999999
 }
```

But, I don't want to use span tag like following code.

ex)

HTML

```
<a class="test"><i>1</i>23</a>
```

CSS

```
.test:hover{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999999
}
.test:hover i{
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

But,It is not working.
How can I solve that?

Comment: if I am not wrong you want a underline effect means if you are on 1 then underline should come under 1, if you are on 2 then underline should come under 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.test:hover i {border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;}` does not work because it basically acts as a window through to the line applied to the containing element  by `.test:hover {border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;}`.

One way you could get around this issue is to instead set the line to match the background colour so it masks the line made by `.test:hover`. This does presume that the background is a solid colour, if it is a gradient or image this method will not be suitable.

```css
.test:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}
.test:hover i {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<a class="test"><i>1</i>23</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this. 
Either in your inline style or CSS file

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since text nodes aren't elements that cannot be selected with CSS or have borders.

Once solution is to use a pseduo-element on the preceding `<i>` that is positioned to the bottom and right of that element, like so:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 72px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
a i {
  position: relative;
}
a i::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  /* some arbitrary large size */
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="test"><i>1</i>23</a>
```